# [postgresql - generate months from start_date and end_date base on total_x]

Tags: postgresql

I have three columns in postgresql

| No | total_car_sales | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Jan-01-2022 | Aug-03-2022 |
| 2 | 1 | April-01-2022 | July-03-2022 |
| 3 | 3 | March-01-2022 | May-03-2022 |
| 4 | 7 | Jan-01-2022 | July-03-2022 |
| 5 | 56 | April-01-2022 | April-25-2022 |
| 6 | 3 | April-01-2022 | Aug-04-2022 |

Here example from start_date No.1: 'Jan-01-2022' to 'August-03-2022': I will count only for August-2022 so the result for August-2022 is 5.
No.6 the result Aug-2022 is 3.
Result I wanna generate total_car_sales for whole table like this:

| Months | total_car_sales |
| --- | --- |
| Jan-2022 | 0 |
| Feb-2022 | 0 |
| March-2022 | 0 |
| April-2022 | 56 |
| May-2022 | 3 |
| June-2022 | 0 |
| July-2022 | 8 |
| August-2022 | 8 |

I have tried to use trunc_cate() but it is not works for it
Any help for suggestion for me really appreciate it

Thank you

Comment: I use this select count(total_car_sales), start_date, end_date
from car_sales
group by total_car_sales, start_date, end_date
But the next step I already research alot even on stack ovverflow, but not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of months (`generate_series`) and calculate total sales for each of them.

```sql
with the_table (no,total_car_sales,start_date,end_date) as 
(
 values
 (1,  5, 'Jan-01-2022'::date, 'Aug-03-2022'::date),
 (2,  1, 'April-01-2022', 'July-03-2022'),
 (3,  3, 'March-01-2022', 'May-03-2022'),
 (4,  7, 'Jan-01-2022',   'July-03-2022'),
 (5, 56, 'April-01-2022', 'April-25-2022'),
 (6,  3, 'April-01-2022', 'Aug-04-2022')
)
select 
  to_char(m, 'mon-yyyy') "month",
  coalesce
  (
   (select sum(total_car_sales) from the_table where m = date_trunc('month', end_date)), 
   0
  ) total_car_sales
from generate_series ('2022-01-01', '2022-08-01', interval '1 month') m;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a super start and really fast